# c++ - Error compiling Anax with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I recently motivate myself to code ECS way. So i download anax and tryed to compile it. Here is the problem, i only tryed and didn't achieved it. I generated the file for Visual Studio and upgraded msvc12 to latest version. But now i get this error and I have no idea how to fix it : 
error C2664: 'void std::vector>::emplace_back(anax::Entity::Id::int_type &,unsigned __int64 &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'anax::Entity::Id::int_type' to 'anax::Entity::Id::int_type &'

And here is the code line which throws the error :

```
m_freeList.emplace_back(static_cast<Entity::Id::int_type>(id.index), counter);
```

Does someone has an idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I think it's very clear form error output that it can not covert `anax::Entity::Id::int_type` to `anax::Entity::Id::int_type&`.

Comment: Well the thing is that i didn't wrote anax and i don't know how to fix this

Comment: try `m_freeList.emplace_back(static_cast<Entity::Id::int_type&>(id.index), counter);`